# Android: Minimum API level requirement to use Google Vision API?

Tags: android

I'm working on an Andriod Studio project and I'm trying to use the Google Cloud Vision API. I've been trying to figure out if I can use it since my target sdk is level 15-25, but I can't find the minimum required sdk level anywhere in the documentation.

The only information relevant to this that I found was the only sample application on their website and it says under prerequisites "

> An Android device running Android 5.0 or higher [1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/blob/master/android/README.md)

That doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't work for lower API levels. Does anyone know what's the minimum requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk) vision API depends on the Google Play Services which are **curently** available for Android 4.0 and above. So for now I think you can continue using the API for your min SDK version 15.

But on a long run there will be many more cool features that will added to lollipop and above only. So the question is, do you want support or quality? Either comprimise the quality for the devices which has 4.0 or focus on quality by building for 5.0 and above because soon devices below 5.0 are going to be obsolete.

Comment: The function that I need is very basic and I would prefer wider support range in this case. What is the appropriate Google Play Services version for my target SDK?

Comment: i guess 10.2.1 is the current version. Its mentioned in the link, just cross check with your requirements.